# How do i substract from an item in the list?

Tags: python, list, function

## [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbmFg.png)

How do i complete the remove function,i am trying to replace the amount in the list with another but I'm not sure how.

My code:

```
def additem():
    items.append(str(input("item name:")))
    amount.append(int(input("item amount:")))

def showitem():
    for i in range(len(items)):
        print("-",items[i],"*",amount[i])

def removeitem():
    inp=input("item name:")
    am=int(input("item amount:"))


items=[]
amount=[]

while True:
    print("<ad>  <remove> <show>  <exit>")
    i=input()
    if i=="add":
        additem()
    elif i=="remove":
        removeitem()
    elif i=="show":
        showitem()
    elif i=="exit":
        print("Inventory closed")
        break
    else:
        print("command not found!")
```

Comment: Hi, please post your code as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would actually be easier and more effective to use a dictionary for this program.
Here's the code -

```
def additem():
    item = input("Enter the item > ")
    amount = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item > "))
    user_items[item] = amount
    
def showitem():
    for key, value in user_items.items():
        print(key, '*', value)
        
def removeitem():
    item_remove = input("Enter the item you want to remove > ")
    del user_items[item_remove]
    

user_items = {}

while True:
    print("<add> <remove> <show> <exit>")
    i = input()
    if i == 'add':
        additem()
    elif i == 'remove':
        removeitem()
    elif i == 'show':
        showitem()
    elif i == 'exit':
        print("Inventory closed")
        break
    else:
        print("Command not found!")
```

I've not formatted the output that well. But the program still works completely. Also, next time, I would recommend pasting your code in the question instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

```
def removeitem( ):
  inp=input("item name:")
  am=int(input("item amount:"))
  try:
    index=items.index(inp) # Get index of "inp"
    amount[index] -= am # Substract the value
    if amount[index] == 0: # Optional: delete entry if amount of item is zero
      del items[index]
      del amount[index]
  except ValueError: # Item is not in list
    print("item not in list")
```

Also, [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) could be useful for your task.

Comment: im learning python and i didnt even know about half of this stuff, thnks you helped a lot